# I have version 1.1.0 of my movesense. Can I flash the firmware to 1.9 without any problems with Showcaseapp-1.9.6.apk?

Tags: movesense

I downloaded the Showcaseapp-1.9.6.apk.  (I am on android)

I downloaded 1.9.0_hr_wakeup_DFU.zip

The showcase app does not show my Smart Sensor (movesense) in the app under "movesense connection" also can't select device because its not listed.

The following message from the readme is confusing me:
WARNING: in case the new firmware is not based on the latest Movesense stack, the device looses the capability to be updated!!!

Does this mean I have to update from 1.1 to 1.2 to 1.3 and so on?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

No worries, you can update directly from 1.1 => 1.9. However, since your firmware is that old you need to use the "_w_bootloader" DFU packet (contains updated bootloader which was introduced in v1.2). Basic rule is that you'll need the "_w_bootloader" DFU packet if there was softdevice / bootloader change between the two versions.

There may be some issues updating the sensor if you are using the latest Android showcase app (1.9.x). In that case you can download older version from movesense-mobile-lib bitbucket site / downloads. iOS sample app should not have that limitation but you will need also the nrf connect / nrf toolbox apps.

*Full Disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*